# How can a QUERY_STRING be empty while REQUEST_URI has parameters?

Tags: php, apache, digital-ocean

On my local machine, things are working fine, but on the liver server I can't read query strings

```
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; == /purchase?id=2
echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; == EMPTY
```

How can this happen?

Here's the htaccess file content:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: check if you have .htaccess for the re-write and if yes u need to use $_SERVER['REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING']

Comment: On local machine it's the same result as QUERY_STRING but on live server it gives: Undefined index error

Comment: what is your php version. Please check with phpinfo() function and share with us.

Comment: Dump the whole $_SERVER array for a bigger view: die("<pre>".print_r($_SERVER, true)."</pre>");

Comment: @DalımÇepiç it's PHP Version 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.8

Comment: I'm sory but i have to ask this question. What is the method did you use to send data ? POST or GET ?

Answer (score 0):

The PHP $_SERVER array is populated with information from the web server environment and the array keys can vary from server to server.

[See $_SERVER in the PHP online manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).